# How to convert a for loop into a function for parallel processing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dijkstra

I have to run a for loop and each loop will access data from a database, do some manipulation and run the Dijkstra algorithm, then append the results to a final list. The code looks like belwo:

```
def log_transform(x):
        transformed = math.e**(-x)
        return transformed 
input_region = '1.199'
t1 = '20200101'
t2 = '20200115' 
candid_sale_invoices = pd.read_excel('candid_sale_invoices.xlsx')
candid_barcodes = pd.read_excel('candid_barcodes.xlsx')

weights = []   
    for i in range(int(t1),(int(t2) + 1)):
        input_date = str(i)
        sql_data = """select trim(cast(p.Barcode as nvarchar(20))) Barcode ,cast(s.invoiceid as nvarchar(20)) invoiceid
        from sales s inner join Product_981115 p on s.productid = p.productid 
        where s.date = """+ input_date +""" and s.qty != 0 and p.sectionid != 1691.199 and s.RegionID = """ + input_region
        data = [] 
        for chunk in pd.read_sql(sql_data,conn,chunksize = 1000000):
            data.append(chunk)
        data = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True)
        data = data.merge(candid_sale_invoices)
        data = data.merge(candid_barcodes)
        final_edges_df = data.iloc[:,[2,3,4]]
        final_edges_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in final_edges_df.values]

        Gm = ig.Graph.TupleList(final_edges_tuples, directed = True, edge_attrs = ['weight'])

        longest_paths = pd.DataFrame(Gm.shortest_paths_dijkstra(None,None, weights = 'weight'))
        longest_paths = longest_paths.swifter.apply(log_transform)
        longest_paths["Date"] = input_date
        longest_paths["RegionID"] = input_region
        weights.append(longest_paths)

weights = pd.concat(weights, ignore_index = True)
```

The problem is with the process time which will take hours to finish. So since each iteration is independent from other iterations, I decided to run this loop in parallel with the help of [this link.](https://hpc-carpentry.github.io/hpc-python/06-parallel/)

```
import psutil
from multiprocess import Pool
pool = Pool(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
def graph_analysis(i):
    input_date = str(i)
    sql_data = """select trim(cast(p.Barcode as nvarchar(20))) Barcode ,cast(s.invoiceid as 
    nvarchar(20)) invoiceid
    from sales s inner join Product_981115 p on s.productid = p.productid 
    where s.date = """+ input_date +""" and s.qty != 0 and p.sectionid != 1691.199 and s.RegionID = """ + input_region
    data = [] 
    for chunk in pd.read_sql(sql_data,conn,chunksize = 1000000):
         data.append(chunk)
    data = pd.concat(data, ignore_index = True)
    data = data.merge(candid_sale_invoices)
    data = data.merge(candid_barcodes)
    final_edges_df = data.iloc[:,[2,3,4]]
    final_edges_tuples = [tuple(x) for x in final_edges_df.values]

    Gm = ig.Graph.TupleList(final_edges_tuples, directed = True, edge_attrs = ['weight'])

    longest_paths = pd.DataFrame(Gm.shortest_paths_dijkstra(None,None, weights = 'weight'))
    longest_paths = longest_paths.swifter.apply(log_transform)
    longest_paths["Date"] = input_date
    longest_paths["RegionID"] = input_region
    Return longest_paths

results = pool.map(graph_analysis,range(int(t1),(int(t2) + 1)))
pool.close()
```

First I got the error for "input_region"

> NameError: name 'input_region' is not defined

which stated that the function didn't recognize it. I know this is a global variable but couldn't figured out how to reuse it inside my function. Since it's the first time I wanted to apply multi-processing, I decided to manually type the "input_region" inside the function and change it afterwards. However the second problem was this:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 66, in 
>       results = pool.map(graph_analysis,range(int(t1),(int(t2) + 1)))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py",
>   line 268, in map
>       return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py",
>   line 657, in get
>       raise self._value
>
> NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Is the whole process which I'm trying to do false?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function that shall be run in a separate process may not have any dependencies on the main process. You have to make it self contained by either importing and/or defining any modules/data in you need in your function or providing it as arguments. An `import pandas as pd` inside of `graph_analysis` should do for the current error.